# How can I add padding to JUST the default divider of a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add left and right padding to just my listview dividers because each row should have a solid color at the far left of the screen and if I add padding to the entire list those colors will also be padded. I know I can make my own dividers but I just can't find the drawable for the default dividers.

I've tried to make a drawable like this:

```
    <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

And then make it the divider:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_pattern" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/status_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false" >
</ListView>
```

But the app force closes with this:

```
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at com.bitnation.tubeappy.StatusFragment.onCreateView(StatusFragment.java:79)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1366)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    ... 46 more
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_divider.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020007
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.widget.ListView.(ListView.java:155)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    at android.widget.ListView.(ListView.java:139)
02-20 18:02:15.374: E/AndroidRuntime(13457):    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Post more of the `Exception` log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue, `android:divider` requires a `@drawable` or `@color` (see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3adivider)), but you are giving it a `@layout` saved under the `@drawable` folder (that's why it compiles), but crashes at run time.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_divider.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020007
```

Unfortunately, I do not think there are any good ways of referencing the default android drawable list divider **AND** overriding its padding/bounds at the same time. If you get the drawable's source file, you can edit the 9.png file's stretchable/content areas to adjust its padding, however that is rather tedious.

This is the **workaround** I have found (and works just fine): set `android:divider="@null"`, and add your divider `View` to the bottom of the `row_layout.xml` (that you use to bind to your `ListView`). Basically you will be faking the divider, and it will live inside each row rather than in between them, but to the user it will look the same. You will then be able to control the divider's padding separate from each row's padding, which is your goal here.